# PDFCreator to convert pdf to txt in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, pdf, com

Updated Comment: I'm attempting to use PDFCreator to convert pdf files into txt files via PowerShell but it still doesn't seem to be working.

Any help is appreciated!

```
$PDFCreator = New-Object -ComObject PDFCreator.JobQueue
$PDF = 'C:\Users\userName\Downloads\SampleACORD.pdf'
$TXT = 'C:\Users\userName\Downloads\SampleACORD.txt'

try {
$PDFCreator.initialize()


  if($PDFCreator.WaitForJob(5)){
  $PJ = $PDFCreator.NextJob
  }

  if($PJ){
  $PJ.PrintFile($PDF)
  $PJ.ConvertTo($TXT)
  }
} catch {
    $_
    Break
}   
finally {
  if($PDFCreator){
    $PDFCreator.ReleaseCom()
  }
}
```

Comment: What isn't working? What errors do you get?

Comment: It isn't producing the txt file in question. It runs, finishes, and no file is produced.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting that because `$PJ` is `$null`. `NextJob` isn't returning anything.

To guard against this, `WaitForJob(int)` returns a bool, `$true` if a job arrived and `$false` if not, so you should know after `WaitForJob` completes whether there is a job to get or not:

```
if( $PDFCreator.WaitForJob(5) ){
  $PJ = $PDFCreator.NextJob

  $PJ.allowDefaultPrinterSwitch('C:\Users\userName\Downloads\SampleACORD.txt', $true)
  $PJ.ConvertTo($TXT)
} else {
  # Handle the no jobs case here
}
```

You could also do a null check against `$PJ` before trying to call `$PJ.allowDefaultPrinterSwitch`:

```
if( $PJ ){
  $PJ.allowDefaultPrinterSwitch('C:\Users\userName\Downloads\SampleACORD.txt', $true)
  $PJ.ConvertTo($TXT)
}
```

Here is some more information on the [`PDFCreator.JobQueue`](https://docs.pdfforge.org/pdfcreator/latest/en/pdfcreator/com-interface/reference/queue/) API, which you may find useful.

---

To address your issue in the comments, where the file is not being produced, [this page of the documentation](https://docs.pdfforge.org/pdfcreator/latest/en/pdfcreator/com-interface/user-manual/basics/conversion/) explains the logical flow of how the conversion process should work:

> 1. Call the `Initialize()` method with your COM Object.
> 2. Call `WaitForJob(timeOut)` if you are waiting for one print job to get in the queue. The parameter `timeOut` specifies the maximum time the queue waits for the print job to arrive.
> 3. Now you are able to get the next job in the queue by calling the property `NextJob`.
> 4. Setup the profile of the job with the method `SetProfileByGuid(guid)`. The guid parameter is used to assign the appropriate conversion profile.
> 5. Start the conversion on your print job with `ConvertTo(path)`. The path parameter includes the full path to the location where the converted file should be saved and its full name.
> 6. The property `IsFinished` informs about the conversion state. If the print job is done, `IsFinished` returns true.
> 7. If you want to know whether the job was successfully done, consider the property `IsSuccessful`. It returns true if the job was converted successfully otherwise false.

In your case, I'm not sure how essential the profile would be, but it does look like your code fails to wait for completion. The following code will wait for the conversion job to finish (and check for success if you need to):

```
# Wait for completion
while( -Not $PJ.IsFinished ){
  Start-Sleep -Seconds 5
}

# Check for success
if( $PJ.IsSuccessful ){
  # success case
} else {
  # failure case
}
```

---

Unrelated, but good practice, wrap your code in a [`try/finally`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_try_catch_finally?view=powershell-5.1) block, and put your COM release in that block. This way your COM connection closes cleanly even in the event of a terminating error:

```
$PDFCreator = New-Object -ComObject PDFCreator.JobQueue

try {

  # Handle PDF creator calls

} finally {
  if( $PDFCreator ){
    $PDFCreator.ReleaseCom()
  }
}
```

The `finally` block is guaranteed to execute before returning to a parent scope, so whether the code succeeds or fails, the `finally` block will be run.

Comment: Thanks for the help but it still doesn't seem to be working. I've edited the above post to reflect my updated code.